# Google/Gsuite Api: Get current users organizations for non admin users

Tags: google-api, google-workspace

I have a freshly authenticated gsuite user. Via plus.person.get('me') I can retrieve the basic profile information. Additionally via the admin.directory I can retrieve the organizations.
Problem is that the admin.directory api is only accessible to admins. 
How can I retrieve a users organization without requiring the user to be an admin?